# How to unsubscribe for weaksubscribe in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, mvvmcross

In my project I have used WeakSubscribe to subscribe the event instead of '+=' operation.

On the other side, is it has the unsubscribe ('-=')?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107525/how-to-unsubscribe-from-weaksubscribe-in-the-mvvmcross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subscribe using something like:

```
     _token = thing.WeakSubscribe(HandleTheEvent);
```

then you can unsubscribe using:

```
     _token.Dispose();
     _token = null;
```

Note that it's important to keep a reference to `_token` for as long as you want the subscription to last - if the token is garbage collected then the event will also be unsubscribed.

Comment: what type of the _token should be? i have used `var _token` but it does not work fine.

Comment: Please ask a question with a bit of your code and an explanation of `does not work fine` - working by comments too hard