# how to unsubscribe from WeakSubscribe in the MvvmCross

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, mvvmcross

```
_parameter.WeakSubscribe(() => _parameter.Value, HandleValueChanged);
```

I use the WeakSubscribe like the above.

My scenario is when the value has changed the system will add a new parameter and the current will unsubscribe from the event.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781446/how-to-unsubscribe-for-weaksubscribe-in-mvvmcross) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you subscribe using something like:

```
 _token = thing.WeakSubscribe(() => parameter.Value, HandleValueChanged);
```

then you can unsubscribe using:

```
 _token.Dispose();
 _token = null;
```

This calls the `Dispose` code in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxWeakEventSubscription.cs#L91 :

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            RemoveEventHandler();
        }
    }

    private void RemoveEventHandler()
    {
        if (!_subscribed)
            return;

        var source = (TSource) _sourceReference.Target;
        if (source != null)
        {
            _sourceEventInfo.GetRemoveMethod().Invoke(source, new object[] {CreateEventHandler()});
            _subscribed = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this "doesn't work" for your app, then please consider adding code that replicates the problem - preferably a block of code that someone could read and run (see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).